# Надо разобраться,что происходит в куске кода

Tags: нейронные-сети, логика

Есть кусок кода нейронной сети, которую писал по инструкциям одного человека. Однако, я никак не могу понять, по какому принципу сравниваются два массива. Объясните на максимально понятном языке, а то мне крайне сложно понимать, что я делаю, если не представляю, основываясь на чем машина принимает решения.

```
trn_inp=np.array([[0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1]])  #Массив 4 на 1. 4 списка по 1 значению

trn_out=np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T   #Ожидаемые выходные данные    ЧТО ЭТО ЗНАЧИТ С ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ ЛОГИКИ?

np.random.seed(mt.ceil(dt_time.second/5)) #"зарождение семени" для генерации ранд. чисел
syn_wei=2*np.random.random((4,1))-1   #Создается массив размером x на y, который заполняется рандомными значениями от -1 до 1
```

Answer (score 1):

.T - это [транспонирование матрицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), можно было бы тоже самое написать и другим способом (таким как ниже в выводе), но так часто короче и понятнее.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T)
```

Вывод:

```
[[0],
 [1],
 [1],
 [0]]
```

То есть на входе нейросети у вас матрица размером 4x4, а на выходе - вертикальный столбец из 4-х элементов.

```
0 0 1 1     0
1 1 1 1 --> 1
1 0 1 1     1
0 1 1 1     0
```

Comment: тогда, мне надо знать, что именно и как сравнивает нейросеть ( если нужен код, то я его предоставлю ). И очень прошу мне, непонятливому,  объяснить, почему из матрицы 4х4 получился столбец 1х4, ведь транспонирование меняет местами строки и столбцы, по факту кладя матрицу на бок.

Comment: И последнее, пока что - где я задаю числа для сравнения, с чем и как они сравниваются и скажите, правильно ли я понял принцип сравнения и разметки. Принцип: В trn_inp я записываю числа, с которыми я сравниваю. В trn_out я записываю ( нужное выбрать ) (А) Единицами и нулями обозначаю правильные и неправильные ответы соответственно. (Б) Искомую последовательность чисел, далее она ищется в первой переменной. Будьте любезны - ответьте на мои вопросы) Мне это очень поможет.

Comment: @LegendaryHunter Погодите, вы как-то сильно торопитесь. Я вам объяснил что у вас имеется, но зачем оно у вас такого размера и какую задачу вы решаете я же не знаю :)  Проще будет, если вы почитаете что-нибудь по нейросетям, где прямо "от печки" всё объясняют. Можете видео на ютьюбе посмотреть, сейчас этого дела полно. Это будет гораздо эффективнее чем я вам что-то буду пытаться объяснять, тем более я не сильно силён в теории нейросетей. :)

Comment: Я вас понял) Просто две книги прочитал полностью, но нигде детально, пошагово не расписывалось, как именно происходит сравнение... Вот и приходится пытаться самому переварить и осознать в полном объеме) Спасибо за ваш первый овтет)